# Are cookies the same for the client, independently from the browser which the request starts?

Tags: cookies

I wish to understand if a HTTP cookie is the same for every browser that starts the request, or if the server generates a different cookie if the browser is different, although the client is the same.

For example, suppose I connect to an Amazon server, first from Mozilla and later from Chrome. Will I receive two different cookies or I will receive the same cookie?

TL,DR: does the server keep track of the client or of the browser?
Thanks in advance.